# Toggling checkboxes in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm having a frustrating problem trying to toggle checkboxes in React.

When I check the box, the state updates, and the state, previous state, and checked display `true` when I `console.log` them, which is weird in itself. But the checkbox doesn't check.

**State**

```
    this.state = {
        type: {
            prop1: false,
            prop2: false
        }
    }
```

**Handling event change**

```
handleCheckbox(e) {
    const name = e.target.name;
    const checked = e.target.checked;
    this.setState((prevState) => {
        this.state.type[name] = !prevState.type[name];
    });
}
```

**Checkbox**

```
<input
   type="checkbox"
   name="prop1"
   id="string"
   className="modal__checkbox-input"
   checked={this.state.type.prop1}
   onChange={this.handleCheckbox}
/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your functional setState, you need to return the state to be updated and not mutate the original state

```
handleCheckbox(e) {
    const name = e.target.name;
    const checked = e.target.checked;
    this.setState((prevState) => {
        return {
           type: {
              ...prevState.type,
              [name]: !prevState.type[name]
           }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

update your handleCheckbox 
old state you will find as this.state

```
handleCheckbox(e) {
    const name = e.target.name;
    const checked = e.target.checked;
    const d = this.state.type;
    d[name] = !d[name];
    this.setState({ type : d });
}
```

Comment: I'm getting errors in the console and my code editor highlights the setState code as red if I try this.